# media query not working in email template

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

i am using the custom email template using html and css . i want to pass the css using media query for the mobile device like:- iphone and retina display on mac and phone. anyone know about this please help
Thanks

Comment: retina devices (iPhone and Mac's) support media queries. If you have a specific code question then edit your question with it please. Posts like this get flagged.

Answer (score 1):

`@media` is not 100% supported in all email clients. check which email client support `@media` from https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=media

[image]